# It's really odd,why setflashmode doen't show in sdk 5?

Tags: android, flash, sdk

I am using android studio and sdk 5 (android 2.2)

it's my code

```
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;

Camera cam;
Camera.Parameters p = cam.getParameters();

cam = Camera.open();
Parameters p = cam.getParameters();
p.
```

after I put p.

setFlashMode doesnt show instantly, and If I write it in.the android studio throw out an error

“can not find symbol: FLASH_MODE_TORCH” in   **p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);**

so I am totally confused by this odd error.
Any guide or tips are appericated.

B.T.W. I already put  in my AndroidMainifest.xml

Answer (score -1):

use it like this Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF